# ImageView increases slightly in size when moving RelativeLayout (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, ontouchlistener, android-relativelayout

I've got an annoying problem where when i move my RelativeLayout, the ImageView in it increases in size to fill the full screen in width. I've replaced the image with a colored background so it's easier to see.

**Don't mind the way it looks, the layout is a W.I.P**

GIF here to show the problem: https://gyazo.com/ae31b8e70e4f96fe89ba041549db22bb

Below is the code for my OnTouchListener

```
private View.OnTouchListener relativeListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
    {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = (X - _xDelta);
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -(X - _xDelta);
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        _root.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
};
```

Below is the xml that defines the ImageView and RelativeLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="me.tech.myapp.Fragments.HomeFragment">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCurrentTheme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="StringCurrentTheme"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMainImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="Foto jonguh"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReportImage"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivMainImage"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSendImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnReportImage"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`? And why do you use `cropToPadding="false"` in your `Imageview`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It was my understanding that `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` was required becouse i am constantly detecting where the users finger is on the screen when it is pressed (correct me if i'm wrong). And the `cropToPadding="false"` is also required for later (I wasn't sure if it's false by default or not)

Comment: @Tonteria24 But it works like this tho, only that little problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by just changing the width manually in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Try to add these to properties to ImageView

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, these changes do not fix the problem, also i need to have centerCrop as it's going to be essential for later.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that the ImageView to occupy the entire layout if you have

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMainImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
....
```

try wrap_content instead match_parent

Comment: But it needs to be the fill as much width as possible tho, that's why I've got it like `android:layout_margin="8dp"`.